# Nodejs/Expressjs router not responding at all at specific endpooint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to implement an endpoint for fetching all locations of a restaurant. In my api.js file I specify all the routes to be used:

```js
const restaurants = require('./routes/restaurants');
...
api.use('/restaurants', restaurants);
...
module.exports = api;
```

In restaurants.js file, I have defined the following GET endpoint:

```js
const RestaurantController = require("../controllers/restaurant.controller");
...
router.get("/locations", RestaurantController.getLocations);
...
module.exports = router;
```

However when I make a request at *localhost:PORT/restaurants/locations*, the request does not respond at all, instead it keeps loading (tried on Postman, Insomnia and Firefox). Furthermore, in my controller I just return an empty array and make a console.log before that and do not get any output. What could be the issue?

Edit: Below is a screenshot of the RestaurantController:

[image]

Comment: show us RestaurantController implementation.

Comment: @Robert I put a screenshot in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok. So just put console.log on each step and check what happening.

```js
const restaurants = require('./routes/restaurants');
...
api.use('/restaurants', (...args) =>{
    console.log("router restaurants hit", args)
    return restaurants(...args)
});
...
module.exports = api;
```

```js
const RestaurantController = require("../controllers/restaurant.controller");
console.log("RestaurantController", RestaurantController, RestaurantController.getLocations);

router.get("/locations", (...args) => {
    console.log("route /restaruan/locations - hit", args); 
    return RestaurantController.getLocations(...arg)
});
...
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I see that the second console.log from the second code snippet (router.get("/locations", ...)) isn't getting printed out but the first console.log from the second code snippet is correctly showing the registered controller function getLocations...

Comment: @Minmax Only for clarification your Router (router.get) object is this one imported from express ? var router = express.Router()